# Counting an object depends on a column instead of table SQL

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to help me on counting the chair that had appear on Monday,Tuesday, and Wednesday instead of the number of the chairs appear in the table?

I expect to get the count of the chair depends on the Order Column instead of the whole table, so the answer will be 3(the chair had appear in monday,tuesday and wednesday) instead of the total number of the chair had appear in the table

[image]

Comment: is there another column that will determine the sequnce of records that you shown here ? You have several `Chair` record and the `Order` is NULL value. How to determine which Chair is for which `Order`

Comment: Maybe i should ask why the `Order` column value is NULL for most of the rows ?

Comment: @Squirrel i have updated the table without null, the count will be 3(days) instead of 5(total appear times in table)

Comment: @Squirrel I have another question, can it show which Order it has been appear? like the out put is 3 times follow by (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday) , is it possible to show the Order follow by the total count number? or in other line

Comment: sure. I will update my post to with the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use count (distinct *column name*)

```
SELECT  COUNT ( DISTINCT Order )
FROM    yourtable
WHERE   Stuff = 'Chair'
```

EDIT :

> I have another question, can it show which Order it has been appear?
>   like the out put is 3 times follow by (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday) , is
>   it possible to show the Order follow by the total count number? or in
>   other line

is this what you wanted ?

```
SELECT  Order, COUNT (*)
FROM    yourtable
WHERE   Stuff = 'Chair'
GROUP BY Order
```

or perhaps this ?

```
SELECT  COUNT ( DISTINCT Order ),
        STUFF ((SELECT ',' + Order  
                FROM yourtable
                WHERE Stuff = 'Chair'
                GROUP BY Order
                FOR XML PATH ('')),
              1, 1, '')
FROM    yourtable
WHERE   Stuff = 'Chair'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are so good at it, i have seen many of your answer in other places